# VSTS Maven package release

Tags: maven, azure-devops, release-management

We produce APIs that are used by third party developers and are using VSTS for our release process.

Currently we use a CI build action that runs when master is updated. This will deploy a new version of the package to our internal feed that can then go through final testing. (unit tests, etc will have been run as part of the verification of the pull request into master)

The question is, when we want to make that package public, can we somehow copy it to a different feed? From what we can find online it appears that the only way to do it is to go through the Maven build process again targeting the public feed.

Comment: You can publish a maven package to another feed in spearately stpe as the link shows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-maven?view=vsts#publish-an-artifact. Or if you want to copy the maven package to anoth0er feed, you can do it in the last step of your CI build (as Rodrigo mentions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make your CI build publish artifacts. There is a build task with that name.
This will make the build to have the binaries in a drop location.

Then create a release and add your CI build as artifact.
On the desired environment, add a task or powershell script to publish your build artifact to your public feed location.